# How to plot multiple category on the same y-axis using plotly express?

Tags: python, plotly

I wrote the code as follows for visualization, I have DATE, CODE which I am showing as a scatter chart using plotly and color it based on source.

X axis shows the time, Y axis shows the CODE (categorical variable)

1- How to show each different source on the same Y axis but their Y axis defined?? currently it is no the same Y axis.
2- How to show each of this category on different chart but all attached and stacked together?

```
a sample of data

     ID     DATE        CODE                SOURCE
0   P04  2016-08-08      f                  m1
1   P04  2015-05-08      f                  m1
2   P04  2010-07-20      v                  m3
3   P04  2013-12-06      g                  m4
4   P08  2018-03-01      h                  m4



def char():
  color_discrete_map = {'df1': 'rgb(255,0,0)',
                      'df2': 'rgb(0,255,0)',
                      'df3': '#11FCE4',
                      'df4': '#9999FF',
                      'df5': '#606060',
                      'df6': '#CC6600'}


    fig = px.scatter(df, x='DATE', y='CODE', color='SOURCE', width=800,
                     height=500,color_discrete_map=color_discrete_map)

    fig.update_layout(xaxis_type='category')

    fig.update_layout(
        margin=dict(l=250, r=0, t=0, b=20),

    )
    fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(tickformat="%y-%m"))

    fig.update_xaxes(ticks= "outside",
                     ticklabelmode= "period", 
                     tickcolor= "black", 
                     ticklen=10, 
                     minor=dict(
                         ticklen=4,  
                         dtick=7*24*60*60*1000,  
                         tick0="2016-07-03", 
                         griddash='dot', 
                         gridcolor='white')
                    )

    # fig.update_layout(xaxis_tickformat = '%d %B (%a)<br>%Y')

    st.plotly_chart(fig)
```

what I want (but scatter) :
[image]

What I produce:

[image]

Comment: Isn't your goal already achieved? `px.scatter(df, x='DATE', y='CODE', color='SOURCE', width=800,height=500,color_discrete_map=color_discrete_map)` Why do you need a sub-axis for your desired outcome?

Comment: because  regarding each source, my data has different CODE (category ) that I  have to show them on different y axis, also data is huge, I can not show all in one Y axis

Comment: With reference to the [examples](https://plotly.com/python/multiple-axes/#multiple-axes) in the expected output, what goes wrong?

Comment: I also updated what I have produced now. I want all of these data overlap but also showing what is their Y axis

Comment: I did try with that example, how should I remove the line chart, I only want the scatter.

Comment: The problem is, the the CODE in one source is numerical but  it is showing with 50K, 100K, but I want the real number shown, the other problem is text of y axis would overlap..